# What's linux kernel equivalent of lseek?

Tags: linux, module, kernel, linux-device-driver, lseek

I'm writing a linux device driver with linux kernel modules, and I want handle situation when user writes after size of the file. I saw there is vfs_lseek(), but it takes an fd, insted I have only struct* file pointer.
I could use an equivalent of lseek in kernel module?

Comment: The proper name of the function is `vfs_llseek` and it takes a `struct file` argument: the function's signature is `loff_t vfs_llseek(struct file *file, loff_t offset, int whence)`.

Comment: It's an extremely unusual requirement for a kernel module to perform a seek operation unless the kernel module opened the file itself. That suggests you are doing something wrong. However, it _is_ common for a driver to _implement_ the `llseek` file operation, and to check the position in its `write` file operation.

Comment: I have to flush content on a file opened by the driver, but offset could be different from 0, so I have to use lseek

Comment: Do you always write to the end of the file? If so, you could set the `O_APPEND` flag in the `flags` parameter when calling `filp_open()`.

Comment: Driver must not open files. You can do it, but it's wrong. Is it some sort of learning / abusing things?